# how to bind Docker Named Volume to host

Tags: docker

I'm new to Docker, 
In docker-compose.yml v.3.7 I have a shared volume (called: apdata) that being used by app and web service as below:

```
version: "3.7"

services:

  app:
    container_name: application
    build:
      context: ./
      dockerfile: app.dockerfile
    working_dir: /var/log
    volumes:
      - apdata:/var/log
#      - type: volume
#        source: apdata
#        target: /var/log
#        volume:
#          nocopy: true
    environment:
      - "DB_PORT=3306"
      - "DB_HOST=database"

  web:
    container_name: website
    build:
      context: ./
      dockerfile: web.dockerfile
    working_dir: /var/www
    volumes:
      - apdata:/var/www
#      - type: volume
#        source: apdata
#        target: /var/www
#        volume:
#          nocopy: true
#      - type: bind
#        source: ../www/
#        target: /var/www
    ports:
      - 8888:80
    depends_on:
      - app

volumes:
  apdata:
    driver: local
  dbdata:
```

above config looks working (no error) but then how do i sync data with my local machine / host?

question: is there a way,  or how to map/bind the volume data to host or my local drive? e.g:

in apdata: web service: `/var/www` map-to local file: `c:\test`
in apdata: app service: `/var/log` map-to local file: `..\log`

so I can read the log in my host (my local machine ) - Windows
and I can deploy or edit my code in my local machine and sync that to container

is this possible?

**edit**

it's not duplicate, let me try to explain more: I have 1 volume apdata, this volume is used shared by 2 services: application and website. and mapped as follow: `application service --> /var/log` and `website service --> /var/www`

and then apdata I would like to map/sync it to my local machine, so i can do my development easily and i can see log directly from my local machine, as follow: `apdata: /var/log` sync to `../log` and `apdata: /var/www` sync to `../www`

Comment: I think it is a different question, i made an edit in my question, to explain more

Answer (score 0):

It's totally possible, indeed, by taking advantage of the `driver` and `driver_opts` settings for such [volume configuration in docker-compose 3.2+](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#volume-configuration-reference)

Based on your example, in a linux file system it could be something like:

```
volumes:
  apdata:
    driver: local
    driver_opts:
      type: none
      device: /home/$USER/data/app
      o: bind

  dbdata:
    driver: local
    driver_opts:
      type: none
      device: /home/$USER/data/web
      o: bind
```

Of course, you gotta make sure that the target files already exist

```sh
mkdir /home/$USER/data/{app,web}
```

As a nice side effect of this solution, you'll be able to still list your volumes the usual way, with:

```sh
docker volume ls
```

and at the same time, you'll be able to directly access to all of the shared content from you container in the folders that you bind to such volumes in this way.

---

**Update**

A simpler way to do it (for example if you just want it for testing purposes) is to simply get rid of the volumes section (at the bottom of your docker-compose file) and instead bind your volumes directly in the volumes section of each service definition:

```
version: "3.7"

services:
  app:
    container_name: application
    build:
      context: ./
      dockerfile: app.dockerfile
    working_dir: /var/www
    volumes:
      - /home/$USER/mysite/logs:/var/log
  web:
    container_name: website
    build:
      context: ./
      dockerfile: web.dockerfile
    working_dir: /var/www
    volumes:
      - /home/$USER/mysite/test:/var/www
    ports:
      - 8888:80
    depends_on:
      - app
```

For Windows systems, just replace the full path for the host's directory to match your actual folder structure, like:

```
...
    volumes:
      - C:\mysite\logs:/var/log
```

---

btw: You no longer need to link the containers in your docker-compose since now they are linked automatically by docker, so anything that runs within your `web` container/service will always be able to find your `app` service by name (just like if they were actually *linked*)

So.. you can remove this part:

```
...
   links:
     - app
```

---

**Adding an extra example here** (to match your last question updates):

```
version: "3.7"

services:
  app:
    container_name: application
    build:
      context: ./
      dockerfile: app.dockerfile
    working_dir: /var/www
    volumes:
      - C:\log:/var/log
  web:
    container_name: website
    build:
      context: ./
      dockerfile: web.dockerfile
    working_dir: /var/www
    volumes:
      - C:\test:/var/www
    ports:
      - 8888:80
    depends_on:
      - app
#-- end of file
```

When you run it this way, you'll be able to navigate in your host machine to those paths: `C:\log` & `C:\temp` and whatever you copy there, your container will automatically be able to access it (but on their respective mapped paths).

For example, if you copy your updated version of your web-site (or even if you edit it directly in that `C:\test` folder) your container will automatically have that same updated content.

And everytime that your app produces a new log entry (or file) you'll be able to access it directly in that `C:\log` folder, which is, indeed, the same `/var/log` folder in the scope of your app (inside its own container)

---

Now, if you want both contents (the app's `/var/log` and the web's `/var/www`) to share the exact same dir (and thus share the same files and folders inside such paths) then just use the same directories in the left side of the volume bindings

Comment: thanks, but that not really what i want, let me try to explain more: I have 1 volume apdata, this volume is used shared by 2 service: application and website. and mapped as follow: `application service --> /var/log` and `website service --> /var/www` and then apdata i would like to map/sync it to my local machine, so i can do my development easily, as follow: `apdata: /var/log sync to ../log` and `apdata: /var/www sync to ../www`

Comment: When you map both paths (your web service's `/var/www` and your app service's `/var/log`) to the same docker volume, what you're actually doing is making them to share the exact same location (no matter if it's a virtual volume or an actual physical path in your host's file system). So.. if you need them to have different contents (which I guess so, since it looks like want to have one for your site source code and the other one for your logs) then you need two distinct docker volumes.

Comment: thank you, what is `driver: local`  means in your example? and `device: /home/$USER/data/web` the path refer to my local machine or path inside container?

Comment: that's a reference to a `local` path (which is the default driver for docker volumes) in your local machine (the _host_). 
In linux systems, `/home/$USER/` is you user base directory (such as `C:\Users\%username%` or simply `%userprofile%` in windows)

Comment: I tried, yours, but it throw me error: `Cannot start service app: error while mounting volume '/var/lib/docker/volumes/docker_apdata/_data': error while mounting volume with options: type='nfs' device='../www' o='nolock,soft,rw': invalid argument`

Comment: Did you try it first with `type: none` and `o: bind`? Are you using a windows or linux system?

Comment: my host is Windows, 
What should i put under my service app --> volumes, should i remove it?

Comment: Ok.. so.. Let's give it another approach. Let's say it's the easy way: 1) remove the volumes section at the top of your docker-compose file, and 2) in the service - app --> volumes: replace what you have there by just:
`- c:\logs:/var/log` (for the app) and `- c:\test:/var/www` (for the web)

Comment: I'm sorry, i'm not completely got what you mean, to avoid misinterpret, would you like to edit post your answer?

Comment: Sure! that was exactly what I was doing, indeed ;) Updated my answer to describe it better.

Comment: Hi, I edited my question and the .yml file, basically, my app and web service is pointing to the same volume (shared) above yml in question looks work (no error) but how do I sync that to host? so I can monitor log and sync my code? your answer, seems like it's using 2 diffrent volumes.

Comment: You wrote again the same volume pattern than before. Just follow the example in my answer: Instead of using `apdata:/var/log`, change it to `C:\logs:/var/log`. That's it. When you do so, any content in you `C:\logs` path will automatically be synced with the `/var/log` path in your app (within the container). Indeed, this way you're setting them to be the same folder.

Comment: And avoid using relative paths for this. Try to use only absolute paths, for example, `C:\log` instead of `..\log`

Comment: Added a new update to my answer with the exact code you're looking for and more details about it. Please read it carefully, run the code, and let me know if you still need another clarification about it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/195731/discussion-between-saldevops-and-and).